# Laravel 5.8 fill→saveでupdateした時の実行SQLを確認したい

Tags: laravel

Eloquent ORMのflll →　saveでupdateの実行SQLを確認したいのですが、
実行SQLの確認ができません。実際にupdateはできおり、findの場合などは期待通り実行SQLを確認出来るのですが。
何か方法はございますでしょうか？

```
$news = News::find($request->id);
$news_form = $request->all();

\DB::enableQueryLog(); 
$news->fill($news_form)->save();
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

### 実行結果

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

fillの部分のvalueを変えたらupdateされ、実行SQLも表示されました。
何も変えなかったら、update実行されないのですね。